# Sharepoint web service connections

Tags: c#, web-services, sharepoint

I have written a web service that connects to a sharepoint site. What is the correct way of managing the connections. Should i always open a new connection for every call or should i try to use an open connection. Currently im using a function like this:

```
private SPWeb _spWeb;
private SPWeb GetConnectionWeb
{
    get
    {
        if (_spWeb == null)
        {
            SPSite oSPSite = new SPSite(_serverUrl);
            _spWeb  = oSPSite.OpenWeb();          
        }

        return _spWeb;
    }
}
```

Im not sure about the implication or if there exist some kind of connection pooling , any views would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SPWeb implements IDisposable so the best place for it is in a 'using' block or a proper try,catch,finally scenario. Personally, I'd have one asset collection class where I look at what values I need from the connection, assign the objects and then close the connection. Multiple connections to SPWeb are fine as long as they're correctly disposed.